# excel vba variable references another variable

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I am trying to set-up a generic process in Excel VBA to handle connections and reading databases.

Rather than hard code variable names into the module I would like to refer to a passed variable name, which is then updated in the module. This would allow me to use this in any number of applications without having to hard code variable names.

Example
An application has a variable:

```
Dim cnDB1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim cnDB2 as ADODB.Connection
```

I would like to pass the variable 'name' as a parameter and have the generic module update the value.

```
Open_Database "cnDB1", strCnnnectionDetails1
Open_Database "cnDB2", strConnectionDetails2
```

I have done this in VBS via the Eval and Execute command, but I cannot identify how to perform a similar action in Excel VBA.

Comment: There is no exact equivalent in VBA. If you use a Class with public member variables, or appropriately named properties, you can use `CallByName` to do this. I confess I struggle to see a benefit though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sort of answered this by just defining a global ADODB connection, which I'm referencing in my module. After the call is made I'm then transferring the global value to my application specific connection.

Dirty workaround but it works.

Comment: That was sort of my approach as well - wrote class for the app to write parameters to a common location, and a class for VBA to read the parameters from that location. I use the MS doc filename as the lookup key for the common location. Won't scale well but works in a small shop.